# Using threads in Java (while using Observe and Observable)

Tags: java, multithreading

My program consists of three classes in total,

1. Main class
2. Model Class
3. View Class

The model class continuously receives data from an XBee (data is taken inside a continuous while loop), I have used Observe and Observable to update my View Class.

But when I initialize both Model and View classes in the main class, the execution does not move to the chart class because it gets stuck in the while loop, how do I use threads in this case, I am a beginner at using Java

Comment: Can you please include the code you have so far?

Comment: Properly.  You write thread code properly.